# Difference between Unix and Linux

Tags: linux

> [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) is a **Unix-like** and mostly POSIX-compliant computer operating system (OS)

What are the **practical** differences between *Unix* and *Linux* without getting into a flame war, because I'm *not* asking which one is **better**, I'm asking about the *differences* between the two. an **objective comparison** would be *perfect* to me. Thank you!

Comment: I'd agree with the general notion of closing this question, but it seems most people are voting to close because of "opinion-based" which seems objectively incorrect (they even explicitly said they're not asking which one is better). It's a question seeking an objective qualification of the difference. There's no opinion in that. It is far too broad of a statement but I'm afraid if I vote to close for that, it'll close the question for the wrong reason.

Comment: To the asker: the differences are huge and numerous. Modern Unix and Linux are only similar in that there's a core set of functionality that is so old that it was a common inspiration for all the modern iterations. They're also alike in that they're more similar to one another than to something like Windows. That's about as much as I could possibly go into the subject without effectively teaching a college-level course on the subject. If you rephrase the question to be more pointed then it's answerable.

Comment: There are a lot of differences ( one interesting difference is that Linux is free/open-source and most UNIX operating systems are not free , but there are many-many other differences). You could try typing in google "differences between linux and unix" and read the numerous pages it finds, because this topic is just too big

Comment: @Bratchley _seeking an objective qualification of the difference_ that's my point behind asking this question

Comment: @Bratchley edit the question and make it  _more pointed_ , please!

Comment: @010010001 unfortunately, it's still too broad. The question as put would be like me asking to describe in what objective ways you are different than one of your parents. It's answerable in a kind of vague way, but would require too much time to answer in any way vaguely approaching complete. By "more pointed" I was meaning more along the lines of asking a specific question so that the answer wouldn't take 50 pages to answer appropriately. I've posted some vague details on the other answer that might give you a vague idea if that's all you're going for but we can't answer a question this broad

Comment: this should be open, or link to a similar discussion which is more robust / satisfying https://superuser.com/questions/43149/what-is-the-difference-between-unix-and-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a **practical** POV, the main difference between the terms *Unix* and *Linux* is that the former describes a **wider family** of operating systems, while the latter describes a more specific subgroup.

For all practical purposes (thus ignoring RMS, technical accuracy, trademarks and other legal aspects), the term *Linux* applies to a number of operating systems, known as distributions: e.g. Red Hat, Fedora, Ubuntu, Debian and so on.

*Unix* (again, blatantly ignoring technical accuracy, trademarks and other legal aspects) is a wider family of operating systems to which *Linux* belongs. Thus, we could say that all Linux distributions *are* part of the *Unix* family. But people have come to use the term *Unix* to mean **Unix operating systems *other than* Linux**. Examples of Unix that are not Linux include OS X, FreeBSD, and Solaris.

**Asking for the differences between Unix and Linux is like asking for the differences between Mammals and Dogs.**

All dogs are mammals, but one could say that they are generally more suited for being pets than other mammals. That does not mean that other mammals like cats can't be excellent pets.

In the same way, it would be OK to say that *generally speaking* Linux is less expensive than Unix (that does not exclude the existence of expensive Linux distributions or Unix operating systems that are free)

If you want to compare one operating system to another you will have to be more specific, cause otherwise the terms are too vague to make a clear comparison.

Comment: "Unix (again, ignoring technical accuracy, trademarks and other legal aspects) is a wider family of operating systems to which Linux belongs." I'm going to have to disagree with this one. Saying Linux isn't Unix is _not_ some sort of pedantic academic argument, they really are different beasts. "Unix-like" is really the best way to describe it. There's undoubtedly inspiration from Unix, but Linux deviates pretty heavily in a lot of areas. That's especially true if "Unix" is understood to mean the traditional Unix OS's like AIX and Solaris.

Comment: that's why I stated *ignoring technical accuracy*. The OP is clearly new to Linux and Unix to be asking this, no need to confuse him/her getting into details like that. He asked for practical differences.

Comment: And there are huge practical differences. Again it's not an academic point where it requires a detailed understanding of the structure of the OS. There are lots of differences that directly impact your ability the administer the system. Package management, device management, operating system tunables, resource control, and firewalling are a broad set of just a few of the things an admin will need to understand to use the system and they vary wildly even between each other much less between Unix and Linux (for example there's no sysfs in AIX or ODM in Linux).

Comment: Which is a long winded way of saying that "Unix-like" already is setting expectations appropriately. Linux is most like Unix but that doesn't mean it's accurate (even in an pedagogic sort of way) to describe one as being a subset of the other rather than a different line that uses one of the others as a reference point.

Comment: I read you but my I think my answer is still appropriate, taking into account the context. Just edited to state that I'm **blatantly** ignoring technical accuracy...

Comment: And what I'm saying is that it's so incorrect there's no way that's a good way to describe it to someone. It doesn't make the subject simpler or easier to understand, it just says a thing that's not accurate.

Comment: @Bratchley can you give me some sources to search on.. i really want to get into this!

Comment: @010010001 the Wikipedia articles on Unix, Linux  and Unix-like would be a good start

Comment: @SamF OK, i'll give them a try right now! thanks guys.

Comment: @010010001 Since it's such broad subject it's hard to really say what you should do to experience it. There was an x86 version of Solaris, though. So you might try booting to that and just poking around at the internals a bit, configuring devices, managing services, managing filesystems, managing users, etc. IIRC Solaris x86 has CDE but not GNOME or KDE so that might be a bit of a difference. The easiest way would be to just pick random topics you're interested in and research online how you would accomplish those goals in AIX or Solaris (the two most popular Unix variants).

Comment: Just as an example [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixfiltering/) is AIX firewalling, while [this](http://blog.ls-al.com/solaris-11-firewall/) is a Solaris firewall. If the latter looks like a BSD-style firewall, that's intentional, they borrowed the BSD firewall and ditched their proprietary firewall in Solaris 10.

Comment: [This](http://seriousbirder.com/blogs/aix-kerberos-ad-client-configuration-how-to/) is how you configure Kerberos authentication in AIX whereas [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos#Client_Configuration) is how you do it on GNU/Linux (albeit with Ubuntu-specific commands).

Comment: package management on Solaris was also a clusterfrack before Solaris 11/OpenIndiana. Once they introduced [`pkg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21802/gihhp.html) (which introduced a more Linux-like way of updating the system) it got a lot easier though. Still no where as easy as it is on Linux, though. AIX packages...don't even get me started. Just thank god that it supports `rpm` alongside. You still have to deal with their insanely complex notion of a package/fileset/etc, though since a lot of stuff comes in that form

Comment: Defiantly give OpenIndiana a go for the SVR4 flavoured derivative, and also perhaps something like FreeBSD/PC-BSD to compare another direction UNIX went in.

Comment: This answer is why 'primarily opinion based' questions are not that useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Unix is the mother OS**, invented in the 60s. Over time it changed into a standard or certification. Nowadays Mac OS X is certified as UNIX, to give an example. Linux is not UNIX certified.

**The main problem with Unix was that it was very expensive.** You needed expensive machinery, an expensive license, and an expensive administrator. We're talking tens of thousands of dollars or euros a year. Not a computer you buy as a student. This still goes for AIX and Solaris, which are mainly used by bigger companies and organizations.

**Linux** grew out of the wish to have an OS available that was **cheap and could run on common hardware**, like the average PC. One of the features was to make it "free", with a proper license: GNU. It's freely available, doesn't cost anything to download and install, and can run on a cheap computer. Take a Raspbian PI, $40, and there you go.

Technically Linux is built from the ground up, except there where software providers gave away their code. The older UNIX systems like AIX and Solaris are still available, but I wonder how long it will take before IBM and Oracle think it's cheaper to run everything on Linux.

Using Linux as a user or admin, it's mostly the same. Commands are very similar, but there are differences, just as between AIX and Solaris I guess.

Comment: "Using Linux as a user or admin, it's mostly the same." I'd have to ask how much Unix you've actually had to deal with. Once you get outside of certain core areas (like command names and their general purposes) the differences are actually pretty big and easily noticeable without delving into the details of the OS.

Comment: I haven't worked with UNIX much, well except then for Mac OS X, which I don't consider a "real" UNIX like AIX. But even that OS is pretty different from Linux, so there you go.